# Onsen UI Carousel Swipe list item

Tags: angularjs, carousel, onsen-ui

i am using the carousel feature of the onsen ui framework in order to delete items in a list by swiping from left to right, like in ios/android.
The swipe displays a "delete"-button which should delete this item from the list and reorder it
The problem is, the view always deletes the last row instead the one i pressed the button on, however, the row is removed correctly in the dataarray.

Does anyone have an answer for that??

*hope that there is s.o. out there with a solution

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should supply some code so we can see what you've tried. Are you using the `ngRepeat` directive and a `<ons-list>`? In that case you should just remove the item from the data array.

In a controller you create a list of items (can be anything):

```
angular.module('myApp').controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = ['A', 'list', 'of', 'items'];
});
```

In your HTML you use `ngRepeat` to loop through them. To remove an item use `ngClick` and splice the list.

```
<ons-list>
  <ons-list-item ng-repeat="item in items">
    {{ item }}
    <ons-button ng-click="items.splice($index, 1)">Remove item</ons-button>
  </ons-list-item>
</ons-list>
```

I've used carousel in the following example, but it shouldn't really matter what you put in your list.
http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/qEmjEB

Comment: Hi Andy, thank you!! Works!
The interesting fact about this, is that i almost had the same approach..but didnt work. Then i copied yours and no problem!!

Cheers!

Comment: Hello Andy, thank you for this idea. But how about swiping right instead of swiping left? How can I do that?

Comment: Sure. Just switch the carousel items and set initial-index="0" in the codepen example: http://codepen.io/argelius/pen/NPEoYm

Comment: Ok cool. How about swiping right with specific distance to stop. Something like  putting max-slide-distance. Where in "remove" button will just exactly show. Just like in ios deleting message list item.

Comment: Yes, that shouldn't be a problem with some tweaking.