# How to manage certain carousel in <ons-list>

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui

I have almost the same question as in [Onsen UI Carousel Swipe list item](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28031146/2500413) question. But I need to manage a certain carousel (ccall functions a la setActiveCarouselItemIndex()) in ons-list-item tapped on instead of removing list member. 
I wrote the code below:

```
 <ons-page ng-controller="TaskListCtrl">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Home</div>
  </ons-toolbar>

  <ons-list>
    <ons-list-item modifier="chevron" ng-controller="TaskItemCtrl" ng-repeat="task in tasks">
      <ons-row>
        <ons-col width="60px">
          {{ task.id }}
        </ons-col>
        <ons-col>
          <ons-carousel var="taskCarousel" auto-scroll style="width: 100%; height: 70px" ng-click="nextView()">
            <ons-carousel-item>
              View #1 {{ task.descr }}
            </ons-carousel-item>
            <ons-carousel-item>
              View #2 {{ task.details }}                  
            </ons-carousel-item>
          </ons-carousel>
        </ons-col>
      </ons-row>
    </ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>
</ons-page>
```

The code is:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['onsen']);

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {

});

app.controller('TaskListCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.tasks = [
            {
                id: "1",
                descr: "Task Description #1",
                details: "Details of Task #1"
            },
            {
                id: "2",
                descr: "Task Description #2",
                details: "Details of Task #1"
            },
            {
                id: "3",
                descr: "Task Description #3",
                details: "Details of Task #1"
            },
            {
                id: "4",
                descr: "Task Description #4",
                details: "Details of Task #1"
            }
        ];

    });

    app.controller('TaskItemCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.nextView = function() {
            var currentIndex = $scope.taskCarousel.getActiveCarouselItemIndex();
            $scope.taskCarousel.setActiveCarouselItemIndex((currentIndex + 1) % 2);            alert($scope.task.descr + "\n" + $scope.taskCarousel.toString());

        };
    }]);
```

A tapping any item in list manages only a carousel at the last ons-list-item.

Thank you in advance...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your code you are naming every carousel item as `var="taskCarousel"`. The problem is that every new carousel item with ng-repeat is "overwriting" the previous `var="taskCarousel"`, so in the end it can only access to the last one. A possible solution would be to name your items dynamically with, for example, your tasks ids:

```
<ons-carousel var="{{task.id}}" auto-scroll style="width: 100%; height: 70px" ng-click="nextView(task.id)">
   <ons-carousel-item>
      View #1 {{ task.descr }}
   </ons-carousel-item>
        <ons-carousel-item>
       View #2 {{ task.details }}                  
   </ons-carousel-item>
</ons-carousel>
```

Notice that now we also send this id when an item is clicked with `ng-click="nextView(task.id)"`. Therefore, in the controller we will need to use bracket notation instead of dot notation to access the element since the parameter we are sending is just a string:

```
app.controller('TaskItemCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
   $scope.nextView = function(taskID) {
       var currentIndex = $scope[taskID].getActiveCarouselItemIndex();
       $scope[taskID].setActiveCarouselItemIndex((currentIndex + 1) % 2);
   };
}]);
```

[You can try it in Codepen here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RNgaWd).
Hope it helps :)

Comment: Oh, thank you. I understand your solution. I supposed `TaskItemCtrl` will be created for each list item and `taskCarousel` will be created at the scope of certain `TaskItemCtrl`. It looks I was wrong. It is not clean part of angular for me... But thank you a lot anyway...